# не нормальный размер макета figma

Tags: html, css, figma

хочу спросить совет, нашел я на каком-то сайте бесплатный макет визитки на figma, красиво выглядит, но размер фрейма 3099х2323, так вот как мне просто на глаз верстать или есть какие-нибудь варианты решение данной проблемы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: макет то покажи

Comment: вот, я отредактировал

Comment: офтоп, интересно куда это такие габариты, на телек?

Answer (score 1):

Хотите pixel-perfect? Экспортируйте весь макет как одно изображение, и поставьте его как `background` вашему `body`. Ну и верстайте.

Второй способ - поделите все значения на нужный множитель, и верстайте. Допустим, у вас экран шириной 1920 (это должна быть ширина именно в браузере, с учетом масштабирования и тп), `3100/1920=1.615`. Делите все значения отступов, размеры шрифтов, высоту и ширину блоков и тп на `1.615`, и верстайте как обычно.

Можно объединить оба способа)

Comment: пожалуй попробую в пропорциях верстать, спасибо за совет